How to sort date after using Format function
I have a date column as mm/dd/yyyy. I want this as mmm-yy, for example as Mar-24. For this I used Format function and I am able to get the desired result. But when I am taking this new date in x axis of column chart, this is not sorted properly.
I want this one sorted as date from older to newer. Please help
I have tried Sort by another column method and used 'Date' column for this. But getting error like :

We can't sort te 'LockMY' column by 'Date'. There can't be more than
one value in Date for the same value in 'LockMY'. Please choose a
different column for sorting or update the data in 'Date


Create a calculated column to get the format you need :
FormattedDate = FORMAT([Date], "MMM-yy")


Then create another one only for sorting :
SortDate = [Date]


Then use it for sorting :


You can create a column with numbers that contains only one value for each of the values in your formatted column. For example:
MonthYearNumber = CONCATENATE(MONTH([Date]), + YEAR([Date])

With this, the sorting by another column works fine.

Sorry, function MONTH doesn't add a 0 for one digit months, so the sorting will put October and November first. Here is a better formula: MonthYearNumber = IF(MONTH([Date]) >= 10, CONCATENATE(MONTH([Date]), YEAR([Date])), CONCATENATE(0, CONCATENATE(MONTH([Date]), YEAR([Date]))))
